# How does one convert cdt managed to makefiles?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Recently I started doing a C++ project, and started it using the internal building tools of eclipse, which seemed the easiest approach to this.

However, because this project will need to be built on more than one architecture, I figured it was best to have some other approach of building this on the other architectures, without the requirement of that PC also having an eclipse installation.

Is there a way to extract the makefile from the managed project? Or should I figure out how to do it outside of eclipse? (With autogen or similar?)

**edit**

For clarification: I'm currently using in eclipse, when looking at the project properties, the `internal builder` as builder type. This uses make, and has a checkbox turned on which indicates it will automatically generate the makefiles.

I still cannot find the makefiles though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking further it seems it's possible to change this internal builder to Gnu Make Builder by going to Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Tool Chain Editor.

At this point, the makefile is found in the Debug folder.